# Difference between Sound and Music

Tags: python, audio, pygame

What are the *key differences* between the `Sound` and `Music` classes in Pygame?

- What are the limitations of each?
- In what situation would one use one or the other?  Is there a benefit to using them in an unintuitive way such as using `Sound` objects to play music files or visa-versa?
- Are there specifically issues with channel limitations, and do one or both have the potential to be dropped from their channel unreliably?
- What are the risks of playing music as a `Sound`?

Comment: What have you done to solve the problem you have? Started the bounty?

Comment: @MikroDel I've done quite a lot actually...  I've familiarized myself with the documentation several times and made a couple of test programs.  I need an authoritative source because, being that this is such a critical, potentially game-breaking issue, I need to make absolutely sure that it is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the main differences, as far as I understood it:

#### Music:

- Play one file at once
- Queue multiple files in a playlist
- Have more control over this one stream: Pause it, rewind it, set endevents
- Get more information: Get current position, get endevents

#### Sound:

- Play as many files as you want
- Play each file you loaded as many times as you want
- Each time you play a sound, it chooses a `Channel` to play on. **This may stop another `Sound` from playing**

So, the `Music` object is indeed suited best for playing long music files, since you have more control of it.

The `Sound` object is suited best for playing short sound files, e. g. a walking sound or a gunshot.

However, if you want to have multiple music files play at once, you'll have to use `Sound`. I don't see any benefit of playing a sound as `Music` though, unless you want to be able to pause it.

Answer (score 4):

*Mostly from the two doc pages.*

- Use the music module to control the playback of music in the sound mixer.
- music playback and regular Sound playback is that the **music is streamed**, and never actually loaded all at once.
- The **mixer system only supports a single music stream** at once.
- mixer can reserve channels, that Sound's will not automatically use
- `Sound`s automatically use an available channel
- I think sounds are also used if you may have multiple copies playing. Two gunshots may play with a delay, but still overlapped. Where as music will generally just be using one instance.

See: [pygame.mixer.Channel](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Channel) , [pygame.mixer.Sound](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound) , [pygame.mixer.music](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html)